# How do I respond to a click on the iphone status bar?

Tags: iphone

UIScrollView and UIWebView both have special handlers for when the user clicks on the status bar.  Is there any way to handle status bar clicks in my views and view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get status bar touches that is currently supported is to embed your view in a UIScrollView and implement scrollViewShouldScrollToTop on the scroll delegate, return NO, and treat it as a tap event...

Answer (score 4):

Complete answer:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html

Comment: Crap... sadly that works, but means delving into unsupported functionality.  Update your answer to reflect that there is currently no SUPPORTED way to do it, and I'll select your answer.

Comment: There is no other way to do it that I know of. UIApplication filter the status bar events. I've never heard of a supported way and I don't know if Apple likes it or not.